# Rollover menu displays properly in IE but not Firefox or Safari

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, safari

I have created a rollover menu with custom buttons that displays correctly in IE but not Firefox or Safari.  In IE, the menu displays seemlessly across the top of the site.  In FF and Safari it shows as a few lines of individual little boxes.  I am using an HTML file to call styles from a CSS file.  Both files will validate with W3C.  Any thoughts on how to get this to display properly in all browsers?  Is there a better way to display this menu other than a table with no borders?  HTML and CSS below. Image: [How it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yz0F9.png)
HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <title>PJD</title>
      <link href="menu1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   </head>
   <body style="background-image:url(/images/GradientBackground.png)">
      <table border='0' cellspacing='0'>
         <tr>
            <th class="PJD_Logo"></th>
            <th class="rollover_New_Client"><a href="PersonalInfo.php" style="display:block;">&nbsp;</a></th>
            <th class="rollover_View_Client"><a href="DisplayInfo.php" style="display:block;">&nbsp;</a></th>
            <th class="rollover_Search_Client"><a href="Search.php" style="display:block;">&nbsp;</a></th>
            <th class="menu_end"></th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    ....
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
body {
   color: #e4e4e4;
}

th.PJD_Logo {
   border: 0px;
   display: inline;
   width: 125px;
   height: 48px;
   background-image: url("/images/PJD_Logo.png");
   color: transparent;
}

th.rollover_New_Client {
border: 0px;
display: inline;
width: 125px;
height: 48px;
background-image: url("/images/btn_New_Client.png");
color: transparent;
}

th.rollover_New_Client:hover {
    background-image: url("/images/btn_New_Client_over.png");
}

th.rollover_View_Client {
    border: 0px;
    display: inline;
    width: 125px;
    height: 48px;
    background-image: url("/images/btn_View_Client.png");
}

th.rollover_View_Client:hover {
    background-image: url("/images/btn_View_Client_over.png");
}

th.rollover_Search_Client {
    border: 0px;
    display: inline;
    width: 125px;
    height: 48px;
    background-image: url("/images/btn_Search_Client.png");
}

th.rollover_Search_Client:hover {
    background-image: url("/images/btn_Search_Client_over.png");
}

th.menu_end {
    border: 0px;
    display: inline;
    width: 500px;
    height: 48px;
    background-image: url("/images/menu_end.png");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly suggest that you stop using a table, and instead use `DIV` or `SPAN` tags, or a `UL` and `LI` construction.

Your problem is the `display: inline;` line. Inline elements have no size, so they ignore your `width` and `height` requirements. If you use the table, simply remove the line. If you use one of the others, consider using `display: inline-block;` instead?

Comment: You nailed it!  Both options worked like a charm.  I'll remember to use <div> from the start next time.